# SignalR Persistent connection giving 404 on echo/negotiate

Tags: signalr

I'm having trouble with the most basic example https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Persistent-Connections. I get "404 on echo/negotiate"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The example is out of date.
It's because the default MVC-project calls **RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);**
You have to move the MapConnection to inside the RegisterRoutes, after the **routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}";** but before any other routes.

I hope this helps

Comment: I tried implementing SignalR using the same sample but experienced the same problem. The /echo/negotiate is still 404'ing.. Can someone help?

Comment: Try reading my solution again, it's the order of the RegisterRoutes that is important

Answer (score 3):

I got the exact same error when trying to implement the basic persistent connection sample, and it took me quite a while to realize that it was due to a version mismatch for Newtonsoft.Json, problem and solution described here:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/195

That is, add a section like:

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.8.0" newVersion="4.0.8.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

to your web.config.

Don't know why that section was missing for me since as far as I understand it should be added automatically by nuget, perhaps something to do with Visual Studio 11 beta. Anyhow, it was the solution to my problem.

Comment: thank you man, it took me a while to notice this, if I could give you a thousand points I would

Comment: Crazy, I had the same issue. Locally my app was fine but was getting 404 when calling signalr. I added this into my web.config on the server and poof: working.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps :
1. In `web.config` add or edit rule json

```
 <dependentAssembly> <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"
 publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.8.0" newVersion="4.0.8.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>
```

2. In `Global.asax` Add new:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection<ChatConnection>("negotiate", "/chat");
```

In method `protected void Application_Start(){}`

Good luck !